# Aspose.Word .Net Core 3 setup problems

Tags: c#, .net-core, aspose.words

So i have used aspose.word in a .Net framwork application and it was fairly easy to setup with the setup guides on aspose's website. But when it comes to .Net Core they have no guides even tho they support it.

I have installed the aspose.word nuget v. 20.5 and its in my PackageReference list. The probem is applying the licence file and getting to work.

Anyone here that uses a aspose product with .Net core that has some info to give me?

Right now i have the .lic file in just a standalone map direcly under the csproj root. I guess i should point to it in startup.cs? But i cant get it to work.

The problem is that the responses people have on the aspose forms are .cs files but they are all locked to just the thread starter and mods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in licensing mechanism in .NET and .NET Standard versions of Aspose.Words. Recommendations to apply the license is the same as described in the documentation.
https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Licensing

I would suggest you to include your license file as an embedded resource in your project as described here
https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Licensing#Licensing-IncludingtheLicenseFileasanEmbeddedResource

And apply the license in the static constructor of the main class that uses Aspose.Words. Hope this helps.

Disclosure: I work at Aspose.Words team.

Comment: Perfect answer. Ty.